# update of more than one consenter at a time is not supported

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

My orderers admin and TLS certs expired so i tried generating new certs . created a new config.pb file by adding Base64 of certs in the config.json file and after that created new config.pb and was able to successfully sign the config by reversing the time of my peer cli machine but after getting signature from all the Organization MSP's . when i try to update my new config to the channel. I'm getting this error.

```
Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- update of more than one consenter at a time is not supported, requested changes: add 6 node(s), remove 6 node(s)
```

I have added newly generated certs for all the orderers at once by simply adding them all to the config.pb . what i understand from the above message is that i need to add the newly generated certs for every orderer one by one , Am i thinking correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update one consenter at a time and you'll do to do this for each channel as well.